# Set size for drompdown in navigation menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, width, html-lists

I have a menu. And it has a dropdown. I want the same size of the parent for the dropdown also.

**My HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="noChild"><a href="#" class="" >MY ACCOUNTS</a></li>
    <li class="noChild "><a  href="#" >LIBRARY</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">OUR DEPOSIT OFFERS </a>
    <ul>
        <li  class="dropdownSizeDn"><a  href="#">OFFERS 1 </a></li>
        <li class="dropdownSizeDn"><a  href="#">OFFERS 2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdownSizeDn"><a  href="#">OFFERS 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li class="noChild"><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery("#menu1 li").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
       .css({
           visibility: "visible",
           display: "none",
           marginLeft:"0px",
           paddingLeft:"0px"})
       .show(200);
},function(){
    jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

From the above code I need to set the same width of "OUR DEPOSIT OFFERS" for all its childern("OFFERS 1 ","OFFERS 2 ","OFFERS 3"). Here I can do it with Jquery. Like

```
jQuery('.dropdownSizeDn').css('width',widthLi + "px");
```

On hover of the corresponding parent. But I would like to set it by CSS itself. Is there any way for this? I dont prefer any css3 fix. It has to be compatible with older browsers.

**EDIT**
I cant hard code the width of each child
.This is My css [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/M5EWW/)

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of each child in the drop-down to be the same fixed width of the parent i.e.  width: 120px.

Comment: NO It will dynamically change its size. Something like a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Covering all the bases since I don't know your CSS:

```
ul li ul, ul li ul li, ul li ul li a {
    width: 100%;
}
```